# Removing characters at end of lines using find and sed

Tags: find, sed

For a codebase converted from java to scala there are many files with unnecessary semicolons at the end. Here is my attempt to remove them:

```
for f in  $(find . -name \*.scala); do echo $f; gsed -i $f -e "s/;$//g"; done
```

(Note: using `gsed` since on mac the `sed` is garbage ..)

However this is simply not doing the job - the semicolons are not removed.

Note that running on a single file like:

```
for f in  $(find . -name testfile); do echo $f; gsed -i $f -e "s/;$//g"; done
```

*does* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use this:

```
for f in  $(find . -name \*.scala); do echo $f; gsed -i $f -e "s/\x0D$//"; done
```

This works *until* you have a file whose name has whitespace or other shell-active characters.  For one, the shell will perform both *word splitting* and *pathname expansion* on the output of `$(find . -name \*.scala)`.  Even without that, the shell will perform *word splitting*  and *pathname expansion* on the unquoted occurrences of `$f` in the `echo` and `gsed` commands.

In this case, fortunately, it is easy to write code that will work reliably: just use find's `-exec` option:

```
find . -name \*.scala -print -exec gsed -i -e 's/\x0D$//g' {} +
```

If you want to remove the trailing semicolons at the same time, then just add one more substitution command to the `sed` script:

```
find . -name \*.scala -print -exec gsed -i -e 's/\x0D$//g; s/;$//;' {} +
```

Comment: Nice catches. when is using `for` better than `-exec` (if ever) ?

Comment: @javadba One uses `for` when the data is already in a shell variable.  For example, to operate on the arguments to a script, one uses `for v in "$@"; do...`.  When reading information from a file or from another command, such as `find`, `for` usually should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to run all of those through `dos2unix` before running sed.  How to get dos2unix you might ask?  Well, this is the main reason to add another answer here (and because I don't have enough rep to add comments yet).  If you want to survive OSX, you need the [Homebrew package manager](http://brew.sh/).  First thing after installing Homebrew (2 minutes) is to *update the bash*!!  OSX hasn't updated bash in years.  With that you can update the unix utilities.

In case you've had bad experiences with MacPorts and Fink in the past, Homebrew is not like that.  Really.  OSX without Homebrew is like Windows without Cygwin.  Well, not really; but you get the idea.

Comment: homebrew has been the one and only way i've done it for my several years on mac - so yea agreed on that.  in any case the command shown below worked fine - it does the same as dos2unix

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: the files had `^M` (DOS style `CRLF`) in them - so first I had to do:

```
for f in  $(find . -name \*.scala); do echo $f; gsed -i $f -e "s/\x0D$//"; done
```

Then subsequently the command shown in the OP works fine.